# Recursively add file-index to dictionary in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, recursion

I would like to add text from a file in a dictionary, called "data". The file looks like this:

```
part-a
    thing-a
    part-a-a
        thing-a
    part-a-b
        thing-a
        thing-b
part-b
    thing-a
    thing-b
    thing-c
```

How can I put the file in a dictionary, so it looks like this?

```py
{"all":
  [
  {
  "part-a":
    [
    "thing-a",
    {
      "part-a-a":["thing-a"],
      "part-a-b":["thing-a","thing-b"]
    }
    ],
  "part-b":
    [
    "thing-a",
    "thing-b",
    "thing-c"
    ]
  }
  ]
}
```

I really have no idea, how to do it...

Comment: Your file looks similar to [yaml](https://yaml.org/)

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `itertools.groupby` with recursion:

```
from itertools import groupby as gb
import re
def get_dict(d):
   _r, _d = [], {}
   for a, _b in gb(d, key=lambda x:not x[0]):
      if a:
         _r.extend([u for _, u in _b])             
      else:
         _d[_r.pop()] = get_dict([[j[4:], k] for j, k in _b]) 
   return _r+([] if not _d else [_d])
```

---

```
import json
data = [re.findall('^\s+|[\w\-]+', i) for i in filter(None, content.split('\n'))]
print(json.dumps(get_dict([['' if not a else a[0], b] for *a, b in data]), indent=4))
```

Output:

```
[
   {
     "part-a": [
        "thing-a",
        {
            "part-a-a": [
                "thing-a"
            ],
            "part-a-b": [
                "thing-a",
                "thing-b"
            ]
        }
      ],
      "part-b": [
        "thing-a",
        "thing-b",
        "thing-c"
      ]
   } 
]
```